# foreach loop not entering

Tags: php, sql, loops, debugging, foreach

My goal is to get the country names to print out in alphabetical order.  This is the function I wrote for that...

```
function getCountries(){
    $namesQ = 'SELECT Name FROM `country` ORDER BY Name ASC';
    global $myPdo;
    $command = $myPdo -> prepare('namesQ');
    $command -> execute();  
    return $command;    
}
```

Then, I echo out the names from an array in HTML...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Country Names</title>

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="primary.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="main" action="controller.php" method="post">
            <?php
                $countries = getCountries();
                $countryNames = $countries->fetchAll();

                foreach( $countryNames as $countryName )
                {
                    echo 'test';
                    echo '<p> ' . $countryName['Name'] . '</p>';
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it seems that the `foreach` loop does not get accessed at all, because even...

```
 echo 'test';
```

... does not print to screen.

I changed the index in `$countryName` to `fhsdjk` since there is no such index, but I don't even get an error message or anything at all.  How can I get it to `echo` out whatever is inside the `foreach` loop?

Comment: your passig string you need to pass varibale  $command = $myPdo -> prepare($namesQ);

Answer (score 1):

your passing string you need to pass variable

```
$command = $myPdo -> prepare('namesQ');
(To)
$command = $myPdo->prepare($namesQ);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you are preparing the string `'namesQ'`, but you actually want to prepare the sql statement assigned to `$namesQ`. So, replace

```
$command = $myPdo->prepare('namesQ');
```

with

```
$command = $myPdo->prepare($namesQ);
```

I suggest you to include the `fetchAll()` call into the `getCountries()` function and to just call:

```
$countryNames = getCountries();
```

And, since you have some problems discovering the db-access errors, I suggest you to always implement exception handling. Especially when you are using `PDO` as data-access abstraction. Here an example - in analogy with your code:

```
function getCountries() {
    try {
        $namesQ = 'SELECT Name FROM `country` ORDER BY Name ASC';

        global $myPdo;

        // Hier: replaced 'namesQ' with $namesQ.
        $command = $myPdo->prepare($namesQ);

        if (!$command) {
            throw new Exception('The SQL statement can not be prepared!');
        }

        if (!$command->execute()) {
            throw new Exception('The PDO statement can not be executed!');
        }

        return $command->fetchAll();
    } catch (PDOException $pdoException) {
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($pdoException, true) . '</pre>';
        exit();
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($exception, true) . '</pre>';
        exit();
    }
}
```

Maybe an early answer of mine, regarding exception handling, will be helpful too:

[Exception handling for PDO::prepare() and PDOStatement::execute() + A generalized exception handling scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43691356/cant-update-or-delete-dynamically-with-twig-and-php-oop/43704962#43704962)