# array for PDO MySQL function

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

i have try to use PDO MySQL in PHP with execute command. But i stuck with array in execute command, here code :

```
public static function join2ArAliasAndArValue($values=array(),$alias=array()){
    $data = array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($values);$i++){
        $data[$alias[$i]] = $values[$i];
    }

    return $data;
}
```

always return :

```
Array ( [:id_val] => 01 [:name_val] => tatang [:phone_val] => 0989989 [:address_val] => kemanggisan [:idkey_val] => 100 )
```

and data must be like this :

```
Array ( 
':id_val'       => '01' , 
':name_val'     => 'tatang', 
':phone_val'    => '0989989',
':address_val'  => 'kemanggisan',
':idkey_val'    => '100'
```

)

how to create like that, remove square brackets and add comma every array value, some person helpme please..

and here my function addrecord :

```
public static function addRecordToTable($table,$fields=array(),$values=array(),$alias=array()){
    $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
    $table = stripslashes(strtolower($table));
    $sql = " INSERT INTO $table ";
    $fields = implode("`, `", $fields);
    $newalias = implode("', '", $alias);
    $sql .= "(`$fields`) VALUES ('$newalias')";
    $alias = explode(', ', $newalias);
    $data =  $data = Helpers::join2ArAliasAndArValue($values,$alias);

    /** DEBUG */
    Debug::debugInput('FIELDS',$fields);
    Debug::debugInput('NEW-ALIAS',$newalias);
    Debug::debugInput('SQL',$sql);
    Debug::debugInput('ALIAS',$alias);
    Debug::debugInput('DATA',$data);

    $query = $database->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute($data);
    $output = $query->rowCount() == 1 ? true : false;
}
```

for debug :

```
public static function debugInput($title,$data){
    $action = is_array($data) ? true : false;
    if($action){
        print $title . " : <b>"; print_r($data); print "</b><br />";
        return false;
    }
        print $title . " : <b>" . $data; print "</b><br />";
}
```

__)

Comment: Have you tried to pass array to PDO execute? What happens?

Comment: Your output looks like the output from the `print_r()` function. The real array should not contain any square brackets.

Comment: @TomUdding yes, i use print_r. If with json_encode is `{":id_val":"01",":name_val":"tatang",":phone_val":"0989989",":address_val":"kemanggisan",":idkey_val":"100"}`

Comment: What is your exact problem? Because I don't see a problem here. Could you add your PDO code as well?

Comment: @ikwijaya Don't use `json_encode()` or `print_r()` before passing the arguments `$values` and `$alias` to the `join2ArAliasAndArValue()` function. Pass normal `$values` and `$alias` arrays as arguments and only on the returning result from `join2ArAliasAndArValue()` apply `json_encode()` or `print_r()`.

Comment: data not really save in my db, just save $alias not $value.

Comment: @aendeerei see the code please, iam not passing data with json_encode or print_r, its just for debug output.

Comment: @all hahaha, i found my problem just remove ' single quotes from $newalias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**False function:**

```
public static function addRecordToTable($table, $fields = array(), $values = array(), $alias = array()) {
    //...

    $sql = " INSERT INTO $table ";
    $fields = implode("`, `", $fields);
    $newalias = implode("', '", $alias);  // GOOD!!!: => $newalias = "alias1', 'alias2', 'alias3"
    $sql .= "(`$fields`) VALUES ('$newalias')";
    $alias = explode(', ', $newalias); // FALSE VALUES!!!: => $alias = array(alias1', 'alias2', 'alias3)
    $data = $data = Helpers::join2ArAliasAndArValue($values, $alias);

    //...
}
```

So, `$newalias`is CORRECT (see comments in the code), because in the form with the single quotes must be inserted into the `INSERT` sql statement!

The `$alias` is used INCORRECT (see comments in the code). So, just delete

```
$alias = explode(', ', $newalias);
```

Because you don't need to implode `$alias` to `$newalias` and then explode this one to a new `$alias` again.

**So, correct function:**

```
public static function addRecordToTable($table, $fields = array(), $values = array(), $alias = array()) {
    //...

    $sql = " INSERT INTO $table ";
    $fields = implode("`, `", $fields);
    $newalias = implode("', '", $alias);
    $sql .= "(`$fields`) VALUES ('$newalias')";
    $data = $data = Helpers::join2ArAliasAndArValue($values, $alias);

    //...
}
```

---

### EDIT 2:

I tried to refactor your code in order to give you a picture of bringing some handling strategies together. Please read the code comments for details. I would recommend

- to use **exception handling**, in order to be able to always discover the errors raised by failed database operations (and not just that). You can see an older answer of me, if you wish:

[Exception handling for PDO::prepare() and PDOStatement::execute() + A generalized exception handling scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43691356/cant-update-or-delete-dynamically-with-twig-and-php-oop/43704962#43704962)

- to use **`sprintf()`** when building complex strings like sql statements (but don't abuse their use).

Here is the `addRecordToTable()` function as I see it:

```
public static function addRecordToTable($table, $fields = array(), $values = array(), $alias = array()) {
    // Use try-catch blocks for exception handling.
    try {
        $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();

        /*
         * Build your sql statement using sprintf() 
         * and placeholders (defined through "%s").
         * See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php
         */
        $sql = sprintf(
                " INSERT INTO %s (`%s`) VALUES ('%s')"
                , stripslashes(strtolower($table))
                , implode("`, `", $fields)
                , implode("', '", $alias)
        );

        // I corrected here also, because you had "$data = $data = ...".
        $data = Helpers::join2ArAliasAndArValue($values, $alias);

        $query = $database->prepare($sql);

        // Added this validation.
        if (!$query) {
            throw new Exception('The SQL statement can not be prepared!');
        }

        $executed = $query->execute($data);

        // Added this validation.
        if (!$executed) {
            throw new Exception('The PDO statement can not be executed!');
        }

        $output = $query->rowCount() == 1 ? true : false;

        /*
         * Corrected (e.g. added) here also, because you
         * have to return the results, e.g. the $output.
         */
        return $output;
    } catch (PDOException $pdoException) {
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($pdoException, true) . '</pre>';
        exit();
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($exception, true) . '</pre>';
        exit();
    }
}
```

---

### EDIT 3:

Using `PDOStatement::bindValue` (or `PDOStatement::bindParam`) to prepare an sql statement. A general example:

```
//...

$sql = 'INSERT INTO demo_table (id, name) VALUES (:id, :name)';
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

if (!$statement) {
    throw new Exception('The SQL statement can not be prepared!');
}

// Integer binding ":id".
$statement->bindValue(':id', $id, $this->getInputParameterDataType($id));

// String binding ":name".
$statement->bindValue(':name', $name, $this->getInputParameterDataType($name));

//...

function getInputParameterDataType($value) {
    $dataType = PDO::PARAM_STR;
    if (is_int($value)) {
        $dataType = PDO::PARAM_INT;
    } elseif (is_bool($value)) {
        $dataType = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
    }
    return $dataType;
}
```

Comment: thanks for clean my code, `$alias = explode(', ', $newalias);`

Comment: @ikwijaya You're welcome. I'll edit my answer now, because I want to show you an eleganter way of building an sql statement.

Comment: @ikwijaya Sorry, it took a long time, but I posted now my suggestions by reediting my initial answer. Good luck with your projects.

Comment: some error `Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ''300', 'tukang sapu', '100', 'kemanggisan'' in 'field list' in D:\myfiles\xampp\htdocs\am\application\core\Query.php on line 87` => just remove single quotes **'** in ('%s') and implode("', '", $alias) because _data not really stored to db_. thanks for new code implementation. its great code. thanks a lot.

Comment: @ikwijaya I take it it works now. Or was there a question about the "warning"-code? I thank you also. Oh, to not forget: use the `bindValue()`or the `bindParam()` functions when you prepare the sql statement, instead of passsing the bindings, e.g the input parameters array as argument to `PDOStatement::execute()`. This way you can pass the right data type of the inserting value. See my EDIT 3.

Comment: @ikwijaya Just now I was enlightened: $alias contains the input parameters. So you have totally right to do **`remove single quotes ' in ('%s') and implode("', '", $alias) because data not really stored to db.`** :-) My bad. Now I'll see your other answer.

Answer (score 0):

here my success code :

```
public static function addRecordToTable($table,$fields=array(),$values=array(),$alias=array()){
$database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
$table = stripslashes(strtolower($table));
$sql = " INSERT INTO $table ";
$fields = implode("`, `", $fields);
$newalias = implode(", ", $alias);
$sql .= "(`$fields`) VALUES ($newalias)";
$alias = explode(', ', $newalias);
$data =  $data = Helpers::join2ArAliasAndArValue($values,$alias);

/** DEBUG */
Debug::debugInput('FIELDS',$fields);
Debug::debugInput('NEW-ALIAS',$newalias);
Debug::debugInput('SQL',$sql);
Debug::debugInput('ALIAS',$alias);
Debug::debugInput('DATA',$data);

$query = $database->prepare($sql);
$query->execute($data);
$output = $query->rowCount() == 1 ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but your solution is bad :-) Please see my answer, You don't have to accept it, of course.

Comment: I posted my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

@aendeerei how about this :

```
public static function getAllDataFromTableWithWhere($table,$fields=array(),$key=array(),$key_values=array(),$key_alias=array(),$is=true,$and=true,$orderby){
    $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
    $table = stripslashes(strtolower($table));
    $fields = implode("`, `", $fields);
    #Debug::debugInput('FIELDS',$fields);
    if($is){
        $sql = "SELECT `$fields` FROM $table WHERE "; #`$key` = ':key_id' ORDER BY `$orderby` ASC";
        if($and){
            for($j=0;$j<count($key);$j++){
                $sql .= "`".$key[$j]. "` = ".$key_alias[$j]." AND ";
            }            
            $sql = substr($sql,0,-4);
        }else{
           for($j=0;$j<count($key);$j++){
                $sql .= "`".$key[$j]. "` = ".$key_alias[$j]." ";
            } 
            $sql = substr($sql,0,-1);
        }
    }else{
        $sql = "SELECT `$fields` FROM $table WHERE "; #`$key` LIKE `:key_id` ORDER BY `$orderby` ASC";
        if($and){
            for($j=0;$j<count($key);$j++){
                $sql .= "`".$key[$j]. "` = ".$key_alias[$j]." AND ";
            }            
            $sql = substr($sql,0,-4);
        }else{
           for($j=0;$j<count($key);$j++){
                $sql .= "`".$key[$j]. "` = ".$key_alias[$j]." ";
            } 
            $sql = substr($sql,0,-1);
        } 
    }

    $sql .= " ORDER BY $orderby";
    $data = Helpers::join2ArAliasAndArValue($key_values,$key_alias);

    #Debug::debugInput('SQL',$sql);
    #Debug::debugInput('DATA',$data);
    $query = $database->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(':idkey_val' => $key_values[0]));

    return $query->fetchAll();
}
```

how to use try catch

Comment: I just added something to exactly this answer of yours. I edited it. I don't know, if you can see it. I must go in about 5 minutes, so take a look in it and feel free to ask me, even if I'm not online.

Answer (score 0):

update :

here my code for update

```
 public static function updateRecordToTable($table,$fields=array(),$values=array(),$alias=array(),$key=array(),$key_alias=array(),$key_values=array(),$and=true){
    try{
        $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
        $table = stripslashes(strtolower($table));
        $data = Helpers::join4ArAliasAndArValue($values,$alias,$key_alias,$key_values);
        $update = ""; #must be declare

        for($i=0;$i<count($fields);$i++){
            $update .= "`".$fields[$i]. "` = ".$alias[$i].", ";
        } 
        $update = substr($update, 0,-2);
        Debug::debugInput('PUSH',$update);          

        if($and){
            for($j=0;$j<count($key);$j++){
                $where = "`".$key[$j]. "` = ".$key_alias[$j]." AND ";
            }            
            $where .= substr($where,0,-4);
        }else{
           for($j=0;$j<count($key);$j++){
                $where = "`".$key[$j]. "` = ".$key_alias[$j];
            }
        }
        Debug::debugInput('WHERE',$where);

        $sql = sprintf(
            "UPDATE %s SET %s WHERE %s", $table,$update,$where
        );

        $query = $database->prepare($sql);

        /** DEBUG */
        Debug::debugInput('SQL',$sql);
        Debug::debugInput('DATA',$data);

        if(!$query){
            throw new Exception('The SQL statement can not be prepared!');
        }

        $execute = $query->execute($data);
        if(!$execute){
            throw new Exception('The PDO statement can not be executed!');
        }
        return $execute;

    } catch (PDOException $pdoException) {
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($pdoException, true) . '</pre>';
        exit();
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($exception, true) . '</pre>';
        exit();
    }
}
```

UPDATE :

```
public static function updateRecordToTable($table,$fields=array(),$values=array(),$alias=array(),$key=array(),$key_alias=array(),$key_values=array(),$and=true){
    try{
        $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
        $table = stripslashes(strtolower($table));
        $data = Helpers::join4ArAliasAndArValue($values,$alias,$key_alias,$key_values);
        $update = ""; #must be declare

        for($i=0;$i<count($fields);$i++){
            $update .= "`".$fields[$i]. "` = ".$alias[$i].", ";
        } 
        $update = substr($update, 0,-2);
        #Debug::debugInput('PUSH',$update);         

        if($and){
            for($j=0;$j<count($key);$j++){
                $where = "`".$key[$j]. "` = ".$key_alias[$j]." AND ";
            }            
            $where .= substr($where,0,-4);
        }else{
           for($j=0;$j<count($key);$j++){
                $where = "`".$key[$j]. "` = ".$key_alias[$j];
            }
        }
        #Debug::debugInput('WHERE',$where);
        $sql = sprintf("UPDATE %s SET %s WHERE %s", $table,$update,$where);
        $query = $database->prepare($sql);

        /** DEBUG 
        Debug::debugInput('SQL',$sql);
        Debug::debugInput('DATA',$data);
        */
        if(!$query){
            throw new Exception('The SQL statement can not be prepared!');
        }

        $execute = $query->execute($data);
        if(!$execute){
            throw new Exception('The PDO statement can not be executed!');
        }
        return $execute;

    } catch (PDOException $pdoException) {
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($pdoException, true) . '</pre>';
        exit();
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($exception, true) . '</pre>';
        exit();
    }
}
```